# Where can I ask what is going on with a website if there is suspicious activity on it?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

> I visited The Pirate Bay today and noticed almost all top seeded games are uploaded by a single user with a very high number of seed per torrent. The file sizes themselves are very small which clearly indicates they are not real. How is this possible, how can a single user upload fake torrents for a large amount of games and have them seeded like that? Is It an attack of some sort?

Is there a Stack Exchange site where I can ask this?

Comment: Your question is very vague.

Comment: I personally think piracy is something SE dosen't and shouldn't touch on. And this is something for piratebay to deal with - rather than SE

Answer (score 7):

### General answer

"What is going on on this website", is generally off-topic for every Stack Exchange site.

So: something weird is going on on a (controversial) website.
First, we can't really know what is going on, only the admins of that site can see what is going on. Or if it is being attacked, only the attackers know.
Second, it's likely to be temporary, so the question will soon be outdated.

### Specific answer

For your specific question, it could be on-topic on [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com), but you'll have to show some prior effort. You should explain why these events would not normally be possible, and show a basic understanding of the BitTorrent protocol.

What makes it possibly on-topic is that it is not so much "something that his happening on a website". Rather, it is "something happening in a protocol, that should not normally be possible, and may indicate malicious activity".

Comment: I don't know that there needs be something wrong with the BitTorrent protocol. The answer to most questions asking how does an attacker have so many machines under their control is usually "botnet". I'll bet that anyone who runs those fake downloads will also unwillingly join that botnet.